# Is there a way to search for questions I haven't voted to close?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, search

Every now and then I pick a tag I'm interested in, find some old unanswered questions in that tag to answer, and then take a stab at working through them. I typically do a search like

> [tag-name] answers:0 closed:no

While I'm doing this, I often cast close votes for questions I come across that are either too broad, or underspecified, etc.

The problem is that if I repeat this search later on, I often come across questions I've previously close-voted.

Is there a way to use the search feature to find questions that I haven't previously close-voted?

Comment: For sure you can't use search and SEDE doesn't have your current close votes. At best you can do a SEDE query to find questions in your tag without answers AND a pending close reviewtask. But that data can be up to 7 days old as SEDE only updates on Sunday. Let me know if you find this worth trying.

Comment: hmm.. well, if anything, the link color would be different if you've already viewed the question. So at least there's that. And you could apply your own css to make those more obvious.

Comment: @KevinB That would work well if I just used one computer, but across devices (and given that I periodically use private browsing just for funzies) it's not the most effective workaround in the world. :-)