# Add option to search for posts that were voted to be deleted, closed, etc by the user

Tags: support, feature-request, vote-to-close, search, search-box

I frequently come across questions that are very similar to questions that I voted to "closed as duplicate" or "delete" etc. So currently I have to manually go to the *votes* tab and then click on the respective *menu* option like ***deleted**,* or ***closure*** etc.

Thus I think that a feature for the main search bar, where the user can write something like:

```
"somephrasetosearch" votes:deletion
```

and the above search should list all of the posts that the user voted to delete and that contains the phrase *somephrasetosearch.*

---

Similarly, the following search:

```
"somephrasetosearch" votes:closure
```

should list all the posts that the user voted to be closed and that contains the phrase *somephrasetosearch.*

This will greatly reduce the manual look up(effort, time etc) that I currently have to do for looking up old posts that I voted for and that contains a specific phrase.

Note that I don't want to use a SEDE query and instead want this to be incorporated in the main search bar of the site.

Comment: Related (some opposite): [Is there a way to search for questions I haven't voted to close?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352652/11107541)

Comment: What problem exactly are you trying to solve here? So you find a question and you think it's similar to some other bad question that you remember... and **why** will it be helpful to find the other bad question? If you think both are duplicates, then what you need to be able to find easily is **the canonical**. On the other hand, if you want to keep track of questions you voted on, to see if they actually got closed/deleted, it will be easier to do that manually, probably. Either way, I recommend taking advantage of your personal Saves.

Answer (score 8):

Another use-case I could see for myself:

I want to find questions I have close voted where the close review expired without action.

The close *vote* would remain but it is longer reviewable. Since I tend to cast close votes on new questions, a query like `votes:closure created:..4d closed:no` would find all posts which are not closed and are over 4 days old which is is how long it takes for the close review to expire. More precisely it is 4 days after the last close votes but *very often* mine happens to be last. (If needed, I can manually check the timeline them for the review expiry, in case I voted to close later).

Comment: Related: [Let SEDE users get hold of data on unsuccessful close votes for stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83006/997587)